# Bootstrap positional issues within content

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I'm pretty new to HTML/CSS/Bootstrap but really wanted to pick it up for a long term learning project with JS eventually be included for a idle game.

The issue i'm having is i want the content to be positioned next to my navigation bar under welcome back, I've tried the many ways i can think of to do it but fail every time.

What i currently have is

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Idle RPG</title>
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
    <!-- Side Nav-->
    <div class="side-nav">
      <div class="text-left pl-4 py-4 primary-text text-uppercase">
        <h2>Forbidden Age</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="text-left pl-4 third-text">
        <h5>Character</h5>
      </div>

      <div class="list-group list-group-flush pl-2 text-left">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                        bg-transparent second-text">
                        Armoury
                    </a>

        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                        bg-transparent second-text">
                        Stats
                    </a>

        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                        bg-transparent second-text">
                        Adventure
                    </a>

        <div class="text-left pl-3 mt-2 third-text">
          <h5>Leveling</h5>
        </div>

        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                        bg-transparent second-text">
                        Quests
                    </a>

        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                        bg-transparent second-text">
                        Dungeons
                    </a>

        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                        bg-transparent second-text">
                        Conquer
                    </a>

        <div class="text-left pl-3 mt-2 third-text">
          <h5>Crafting</h5>
        </div>

        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                        bg-transparent second-text">
                        Blacksmith
                    </a>

        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                        bg-transparent second-text">
                        Jewelcrafting
                    </a>

        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                        bg-transparent second-text">
                        Enchanting
                    </a>

        <div class="text-left pl-3 mt-2 third-text">
          <h5>Guild</h5>
        </div>

        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                        bg-transparent second-text">
                        Raiding
                    </a>

        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                        bg-transparent second-text">
                        Forum
                    </a>

        <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                        bg-transparent second-text">
                        Bank
                    </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Side Nav End-->

    <!-- Player Dropdown Start-->

    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent
                    py-4 px-4">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <i class="fas fa-2x fa-align-left primary-text mr-3 id=" menu-toggle "></i>
                        <h3 class="m-0 ">Welcome Back</h3>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button "
                            data-bs-toggle="collapse "
                            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent "
                            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent "
                            aria-expanded="false " aria-label="Toggle navigation ">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
                        </button>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse "
                            id="navbarSupportedContent ">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto pl-3 mb-lg-0 ">
                                <li class="nav-item-dropdown ">
                                    <a href="# " class="nav-link dropdown-toggle second-text fw-bold " id="navbarDropdown "
                                        role="button " data-bs-toggle="dropdown "
                                        aria-expanded="false ">
                                        <i class="fas fa-user me-2 "></i>Yami
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu "
                                        aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown ">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="# " class="dropdown-item ">Profile</a>
                                            <a href="# " class="dropdown-item ">Profile</a>
                                            <a href="# " class="dropdown-item ">Profile</a>
                                            <a href="# " class="dropdown-item ">Profile</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Player Dropdown End -->

        <!-- Main Content Start -->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col ">
                    <p>test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




        <!-- Main Content End -->




        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js "></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js "
            integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q "
            crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js "></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

and [Image to help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93GxZ.png)

It's probably something basic and I'm sorry for wasting anyone's time if it is.

Comment: `<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` doesn't work, I test your code with `bootstrap cdn` instead of your `href` address and it's work fine

Comment: I tried switching the CDN and that hasn't resolved my issue of positioning my content where i want it to be. @jiali (Bootstrap is working fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

set `<div class="container"> ... </div>` in `<div class="content-wrapper"> ... </div>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Idle RPG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
        <!-- Side Nav-->
        <div class="side-nav">
            <div class="text-left pl-4 py-4 primary-text text-uppercase">
                <h2>Forbidden Age</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="text-left pl-4 third-text">
                <h5>Character</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group list-group-flush pl-2 text-left">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                bg-transparent second-text">
                Armoury
                </a>
                <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                bg-transparent second-text">
                Stats
                </a>
                <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                bg-transparent second-text">
                Adventure
                </a>
                <div class="text-left pl-3 mt-2 third-text">
                <h5>Leveling</h5>
                </div>
                <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                bg-transparent second-text">
                Quests
                </a>
                <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                bg-transparent second-text">
                Dungeons
                </a>
                <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                bg-transparent second-text">
                Conquer
                </a>
                <div class="text-left pl-3 mt-2 third-text">
                <h5>Crafting</h5>
                </div>
                <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                bg-transparent second-text">
                Blacksmith
                </a>
                <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                bg-transparent second-text">
                Jewelcrafting
                </a>
                <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                bg-transparent second-text">
                Enchanting
                </a>
                <div class="text-left pl-3 mt-2 third-text">
                <h5>Guild</h5>
                </div>
                <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                bg-transparent second-text">
                Raiding
                </a>
                <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                bg-transparent second-text">
                Forum
                </a>
                <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action
                bg-transparent second-text">
                Bank
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Side Nav End-->
        <!-- Player Dropdown Start-->
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent py-4 px-4">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <i class="fas fa-2x fa-align-left primary-text mr-3" id=" menu-toggle "></i>
                <h3 class="m-0 ">Welcome Back</h3>
                <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button " data-bs-toggle="collapse " data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent " aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent " aria-expanded="false " aria-label="Toggle navigation ">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent ">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto pl-3 mb-lg-0 ">
                        <li class="nav-item-dropdown ">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle second-text fw-bold " id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fas fa-user me-2 "></i>Yami
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu "
                            aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown ">
                            <li>
                                <a href="# " class="dropdown-item ">Profile</a>
                                <a href="# " class="dropdown-item ">Profile</a>
                                <a href="# " class="dropdown-item ">Profile</a>
                                <a href="# " class="dropdown-item ">Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Player Dropdown End -->
 <!-- Main Content Start -->
    
    

    <!-- Main Content End -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js "></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to have done the job, just have to use some css to position things 100% now, thank you!